# Как создать exe файл из jar файла на Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

Подскажите может есть какой то плагин который будет создавать exe файл из jar файла?

Comment: Первая строка в гугле по запросу jar to exe: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @zolt а что разве есть плагин для Jenkins'a, что бы преобразовать из jar -> exe? Или нужно только ставить этот софт локально, и на Jenkins'e с помощью execute Shell преобразовать?

Comment: у этой приблуды есть для Ant и для Maven плагины. Т.е. можно встроить конвертацию в процесс сборки.